# AX 2012 how to set args record datasource in X++

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, args

Can anyone tell me what should I do in X++ to get a NOT null value from args.record().datasource() method after executing the following statements:

```
PurchTable    purchTable;

args.record(purchTable);

if(args.record().datasource())  //this condition fails because of null value
{
    //I have to reach here
}
```

I know that the same code works fine when it is called from Form but my scenario is that I have to execute this code from within X++. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

args.record().datasource() will retrieve a form datasource. Here, you are using a table buffer only. That's why you don't have anything.

If you want to retrieve the table buffer, you might go this way:

```
PurchTable purchTable;
PurchTable argPurchTable;

select firstOnly purchTable;
args.record(purchTable);

if (args.record() && args.dataset() == tableNum(PurchTable))
{
    argPurchTable = args.record();
    //do something
}
```

Regards,

Geoffrey

Comment: I wonder if "args.dataset() == tableNum(PurchTable)" is enough?
There is an example in Forms>CustTrans>Datasources>CustTrans>executeQuery()

Comment: "args.dataset() == tableNum(PurchTable)" is just to test the TableId to prevent putting a SalesTable buffer in an PurchTable one.

args.record() is enough to test if a record is passed.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked

Answer (score 0):

```
 Form pseudoForm;
FormBuildDesign formBuildDesign;
FormRun formRun;
FormBuildDataSource formBuildDataSource;
FormDataSource formDataSource;

QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
QueryBuildRange queryBuildRange;

Args args = new Args();

pseudoForm          = new Form();
formBuildDataSource = pseudoForm.addDataSource("inventTable");
formBuildDesign     = pseudoForm.addDesign("Design");
args.object(pseudoForm);

formRun = new FormRun(args);
formRun.init();

formDataSource       = formRun.dataSource(1);



 formDataSource.query().dataSourceNo(1)
.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable,Itemid)).value("000.0000.00A");

 formDataSource.executeQuery();
 formDataSource.getFirst();
formDataSource=formDataSource.getFirst().dataSource();
info(formDataSource.name());

args.record(formDataSource.getFirst());
EcoResProductValidatonServiceProxy::main(args);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).